# Select random sheet cell value from column to return and log

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm building a web script that collects the information entered in fields and at the end, it allows the user to select a code type and upon hitting "Generate Now":

- Logs all of the information entered in the fields
- Clears all the fields
- Displays the key in the "Your Code" field

  [Input Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL0YN.png) 
  [Data Entry Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh23w.png) 
  [Key Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyDJC.png)

The issue I'm having is getting the Key Code to display to the user once they click on the "Generate Now" button.

I'd also like to scale it by randomizing the way it selects a key from the list rather than selecting the next valid key in the list. This is to avoid people generating keys at the same time and getting the same keys.

This is my first time ever coding so my knowledge is super limited but... I attempted to give the "Generate Now" button 2 functions.

The first function collects the information from the input fields and logs it into the "Data sheet". At the same time, it selects a valid code from the "Keys" list, marks it as redeemed and copies the code over to the data collection sheet.

I tried to make a second function that runs simultaneously when you press the "Generate Now" button. I wanted to use all of the IDs of the input fields and use it as a search function to pull the key from the "Data sheet" but I couldn't get that to work.

```
function userClicked(userInfo){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var keysSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Keys");
  var codeTypeColumn = getFirstMatchingCoord(keysSheet, userInfo.codeType, 1, null)[1];
  var firstValidCodeRow = getFirstMatchingCoord(keysSheet, "Valid", null, codeTypeColumn + 2)[0];
  keysSheet.getRange(firstValidCodeRow, codeTypeColumn + 2).setValue("redeemed");
  var key = keysSheet.getRange(firstValidCodeRow, codeTypeColumn).getValue();

  ws.appendRow([userInfo.memberFirst, userInfo.memberLast, userInfo.memberEmail, userInfo.orderNum, userInfo.agentFirst, userInfo.agentLast, userInfo.codeType, key, new Date()]);
} 

function getFirstMatchingCoord(sheet, value, row, col) {
  if (row === null) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(1, col, sheet.getMaxRows(), 1);
  } else {
    var range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  }
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value_row = values[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < value_row.length; j++) {
      if (values[i][j] == value) {
        if (row === null) {
          return [i + 1, col];
        } else {
          return [row, j + 1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I see that you attempted to put images into your post.  Perhaps you didn't notice that they didn't make it and I hesitate making such a big edit without your input.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @Cooper. Hopefully, the images work now!

Comment: I'd use a scriptlock to deal with simultaneous suggestions rather than randomizing.